# Count the input based on ID & Date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, metadata

I have a Data set which looks like this:

```
ID       Date      Input
1        1-Nov      A
1        1-Nov      B
1        2-Nov      A
1        3-Nov      A
1        3-Nov      B
1        4-Nov      B
2        1-Nov      B
```

i want my output to count the occurrence of Inputs based on style and Date, so output will look like this:

```
ID       Date      Input          Output
1        1-Nov      A              1          ---first occurrence of A
1        1-Nov      B              1             first occurrence of B
1        2-Nov      A              2             Count is two because A was there for Nov1 as well
1        3-Nov      A              3
1        3-Nov      B              1             B is reseted to 1 since it was not present for nov2
1        4-Nov      B              2
2        1-Nov      B              1             Again it is 1 because ID changed from 1 to 2
```

Can anyone please help me how to get this output count of items based on ID and Date.

Answer (score 0):

We make groups of `ID` + `Input` with `GroupBy` and check where the difference is equal to `1 day`. Then we take the cumulative sum of these `booleans`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%b')

df['temp'] = (
    df.groupby(['ID', 'Input'])['Date'].diff()
    .fillna(pd.Timedelta(1, unit='day')).le(pd.Timedelta(1, unit='day'))
)

df['Output'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Input'])['temp'].cumsum().astype(int)

df = df.drop(columns='temp').assign(Date=df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%b'))
```

```
   ID    Date Input  Output
0   1  01-Nov     A       1
1   1  01-Nov     B       1
2   1  02-Nov     A       2
3   1  03-Nov     A       3
4   1  03-Nov     B       1
5   1  04-Nov     B       2
6   2  01-Nov     B       1
```

Comment: Thanks @Erfan but if there are more inputs with the same Date, code is counting that as well